# Opencv preprocess webcam frame before sending it to receiver

Tags: c++, opencv, background, frames

I need to remove the background from N numbers of frame captured from a webcam, meaning I need to process some video frames, then, send them to a recipient (video-conference). 
Basically I need to record myself from my webcam, process the frame and send it to the internet using a video conference software.
I am currently using the OpenCV library, writing the code in C++ and developing on Osx.

**I currently removed the background and I am able to process my webcam frames, BUT i really have no idea how to interact with a video conference software.**

Any ideas?

Comment: As a starting point this may help: http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/videoio/doc/reading_and_writing_video.html#videocapture

Comment: thanks, but not really what i was looking for:)